# ggplot2: CairoSVG changes point size

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2, cairo

I build scatterplots using `ggplot2` in R. I then want to save them as svg files with `Cairo::CairoSVG`. It seems to work fine except for the point size, which is enlarged in the resulting .svg file.

Here comes some example code:

```
library (ggplot2)

my_plot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
           geom_point(size = 0.5)

x11 (width = 6, height = 6)
my_plot

Cairo::CairoSVG (file = "my_path",
                width = 6, height = 6)
print (my_plot)
dev.off()
```

And this is what I get: on the right hand, the plot printed in R and on the left side the saved .svg-file opened in Inkscape. It looks fine except for the point size, which is a pity. Are there any ideas on how to get the right point-size? I tried different point sizes and also shapes, with similarly unmatched results.

Note that I seek to stick with `Cairo::CairoSVG`, beacuse in the final plots I wish to use custom fonts which are printed nicely with `Cairo::CairoSVG`. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: I am working on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary remark: when you pass `width = 6, height = 6` in the `Cairo::CairoSVG()` parameters, you provide potentially different parameters (resolution and display) from the ones used in the RStudio plot panel.

To get the exact same image than the one rendered in the panel as well as using `Cairo`, you can use this alternative (`dev.size('px')` returns the dimensions of the current plot panel):

```r
library (ggplot2)
my_plot <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
           geom_point(size = 0.5)
my_plot

mirror <- recordPlot()
png(filename = "mypath", 
      width = dev.size('px')[1]/96, 
      height = dev.size('px')[2]/96, 
      res = 96, # base RStudio resolution
      units = "in",
      type = "cairo") # calls CairoSVG
replayPlot(mirror)
dev.off()
```

(Note : I prefer the use of `png()` rather than `ggsave()` because it will save the *entire* last plot. I have observed that `ggsave()` would save only the last facet of a grid, for example)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has the same behaviour as the approach that I tried: the points in the resulting .png file are much larger than the points I see in RStudio.

Comment: Indeed, just tried it myself. Not the first time I see this side effect from Cairo.
It would be great if the antialiasing would be available on plot in RStudio for Windows (it is the case for Mac & Linux)... 
The feature request has been opened last year, not added yet : https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2142

Comment: ... which means that currently, there is no option to achieve what I want?

Comment: of course you could adjust the `geom_point` point size in your original code. 
But I think that the differences we observed are inherent in the Cairo device source code...

Comment: I see. Is there an alternative to using Cairo? Most importantly, Cairo works well with the fonts I want to use (ChantillyLH for example). It seems jinxed - either, the font is ok *or* the graph (points etc.). I am really "just" searching for an option to store *exactly* what I see on screen in RStudio as a vector graphic.

Comment: Well, if you remove the `type = "cairo"` in my png() function, it should record exactly what you see in the R plot panel. Can you make a test ?

Comment: however, I need to print a vector image and not a raster image. unfortunately...

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I have forgotten this point. I am not really used to save svg objects, unfortunately.
Just saw that CairoSVG has a `pointsize` argument... maybe a hint. Good luck!

Comment: The docs say pointsize refers to text, not actual circles: "the default pointsize of plotted text, interpreted as big points (1/72 inch) at res ppi."